# Input elements not consuming all space on the line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following form:

```
<form class="form-group">
    <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="Email" >
    <div class="form-group split-input">
      <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="043">
      <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
    </div>
<form>
```

The split input doesn't take all its space like the single line inputs do. Where is the problem?

```
.form-group {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    width:12.5rem
  }

.input{
  padding:.758rem;
  width:100%;
  margin:.3125rem
  }

.split-input{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row;
  }

.split-input :first-child{
  flex-basis:35%
}
```

[image]

Please, take a look https://jsfiddle.net/o2j10goc/

```css
html{box-sizing:border-box;}
*,*::before,*::after{box-sizing:inherit}
fieldset{border:0;padding:0;margin:0;min-width:0}
input{border-style:none}

.form-group {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction:normal;
    -ms-flex-direction:column;
    flex-direction:column;
    width:12.5rem
  }
.input{
  padding:.758rem;
  width:100%;
  margin:.3125rem
  }
.split-input{
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction:normal;
  -ms-flex-flow:row;
  flex-flow:row
  }
.split-input :first-child{
  -ms-flex-preferred-size:35%;
  flex-basis:35%
}
```

```html
<form class="form-group">
  <fieldset>
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="First Name" >
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" >
    <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="Email" >
    <div class="form-group split-input">
      <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="043">
      <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems: `flex-shrink` is enabled, and margins on the `input` elements also apply to inputs in the sub-container.

***Problem #1***

Flex items, by default, are set to [**`flex-shrink: 1`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-shrink-property). This means they can shrink below the `width` or `flex-basis` you set. This allows them to fit within the container.

So instead of just:

```
flex-basis: 35%
```

Try:

```
flex-basis: 35%;
flex-shrink: 0;
```

Or better yet, as [recommended by the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-components):

```
flex: 0 0 35%;
```

> Authors are encouraged to control flexibility using the `flex` shorthand
>   rather than with its longhand properties directly, as the shorthand
>   correctly resets any unspecified components to accommodate common
>   uses.

***Problem #2***

You have a `margin` rule applied to all `input` elements. This margin will apply when inputs are in a nested container (`.split-input`), which causes them to be shorter relative to inputs in the parent.

You have this:

```
.input {
  padding: .758rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin: .3125rem;
}
```

So add this to your code:

```
.split-input {
   margin: 0 .3125rem
}
.split-input :first-child {
   margin-left: 0;
}
.split-input :last-child {
   margin-right: 0;
}
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/o2j10goc/6/)

```css
html{box-sizing:border-box;}
*,*::before,*::after{box-sizing:inherit}
fieldset{border:0;padding:0;margin:0;min-width:0}
input{border-style:none}

.form-group {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction:normal;
    -ms-flex-direction:column;
    flex-direction:column;
    width:12.5rem
  }
.input{
  padding:.758rem;
  width:100%;
  margin:.3125rem;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  }
  
  /* ADJUSTMENTS */
.split-input{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row;
  margin: 0 .3125rem
  }
.split-input :first-child{
  flex: 0 0 35%;
  margin-left: 0;
  }

.split-input :last-child{
   margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-group">
  <fieldset>
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="First Name" >
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" >
    <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="Email" >
    <div class="form-group split-input">
      <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="043">
      <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your updated fiddle. Just add margin-top in .input class and add margin-right in first input in css file instead of margin

https://jsfiddle.net/o2j10goc/4/

```
     .input{
       padding:.758rem;
       width:100%;
       margin-top:.3125rem
      }
     .first{
       margin-right:5px;
     }
```

Comment: @Bavi Gurunath, have a look into the fiddle its fixed now

Answer (score 1):

I removed the margin right and left for the input field. The margins where causing the fields to leave their container. And for the split fields i added margin right to the first input field and made their container 100% making it responsive;

```css
html{box-sizing:border-box;}
*,*::before,*::after{box-sizing:inherit}
fieldset{border:0;padding:0;margin:0;min-width:0}
input{border-style:none}
body {
 background-color: grey;
 }
.form-group {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction:normal;
    -ms-flex-direction:column;
    flex-direction:column;
    width:12.5rem
  }
.input{
  padding:.758rem;
  width:100%;
  margin:.3125rem 0; /**Changed**/
 }
.split-input{
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction:normal;
  -ms-flex-flow:row;
  flex-flow:row;
  width: 100%;
  }
.split-input :first-child{
  -ms-flex-preferred-size:35%;
  flex-basis:35%;
  margin-right: .3125rem; /**Added**/
}
```

```html
<form class="form-group">
  <fieldset>
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="First Name" >
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" >
    <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="Email" >
    <div class="form-group split-input">
      <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="043">
      <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```